# Error When trying to Call Class to Show in QT

Tags: c++, qt, class

I am trying to call and show other window in mainwindow in Qt Creator. This below its my code:

```
ImageDialog imageDialog;
imageDialog->show();
```

but this is wrong and I see this error from Qt:

> **mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ImageDialog::ImageDialog(class QWidget *)" (??0ImageDialog@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_4_clicked@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where is ImageDialog defined? - is that a Qt library?, maybe you can display some more code + the .pro file?

Comment: Thank You All. i will fixed my problem with This:

        ImageDialog *dialog = new ImageDialog;
        dialog->setWindowTitle("Dialog");
        dialog->show();
and add MainWindow header tags into ImageDialog and Reverse.
and finaly i'am Run QMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you declared `ImageDialog` constructor (which takes `QWidget *` as parameter) and didn't provide definition.

You should probably add definition to your `imagedialog.cpp` like

```
ImageDialog::ImageDialog(QWidget * parent)
    : YOUR_IMAGE_DIALOG_BASE_CLASS_NAME(parent)
{
}
```